# Nested Concatenation in BigSQL

Tags: biginsights, bigsql

I'm attempting to concatenate three fields in BigSQL. I can successfully concatenate two fields with

```
SELECT
CONCAT(column1, column2)
FROM table;
```

but I am unable to concatenate three fields with that (only accepts two arguments). I have attempted a nested concatenation via

```
SELECT
CONCAT(CONCAT(column1, column2), column3)
FROM table;
```

But this returns a `Null` value. I'm attempting to create a view but this part of the select statement isn't working. All three columns are `varchar` so I'm not sure where the issue is, unless I literally am just not allowed to do nested concatenations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to pay attention to your data. The third column I was concatenating was defined as `varchar(1)` but every single row had read in `" "` and apparently read it as `Null`. When we are concatenating anything with a `NULL`, the result will be `NULL`. When I ran this code with a different third column it successfully concatenated.